# deducing variadic inheritance type from constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a struct that can have a variadic number of members by inheriting from them:

```
struct A{ int a; };
struct B{ float b; };
struct C{ const char* c; };


template<typename ... Ts>
struct collection : Ts... {

};

int main() {
    collection<A, B, C> n;
    n.a = 5;
    n.b = 0.5f;
    n.c = "123";
}
```

now I want to use the initializer-list constructor:

```
auto n = collection<A, B, C>{ 5, 0.5f, "123" };
```

but I have to name the templates `A, B, C`. The compiler should figure this out.
I want to achieve this:

```
auto n = collection{ 5, 0.5f, "123" };
```

but this doesn't work

```
main.cpp(8,1): error C3770: 'int': is not a valid base class
main.cpp(12): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'collection<int,float,const char *>' being compiled
main.cpp(8,1): error C3770: 'float': is not a valid base class
main.cpp(8,1): error C3770: 'const char *': is not a valid base class
main.cpp(12,38): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'collection<int,float,const char *>'
main.cpp(12,21): message : Invalid aggregate initialization
```

*Visual Studio 2022 17.3.0, /std:c++latest, Debug x64*

---

Is there a (clean) way to deduce the right type? It should be possible with the right constructor, since all underlying types are uniquely assignable.

Comment: Add a `collection(Ts... ts)` constructor?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know the syntax how to assign `ts` to the members.

Comment: I think `collection(Ts... ts) : Ts(ts)... {}` should work

Comment: @NathanOliver this doesn't work, as it would deduce `Ts` to be the underlying types, not `A, B, C`. https://godbolt.org/z/jnhTGjvxM

Comment: well yeah, you have to give it the types you want it to deduce. I might have a wat to get it to work, let me try a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [user defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) and a couple "meta functions" to map the parameter type to the desired class type.  First the meta functions get declared like

```
A type_map(int);
B type_map(float);
C type_map(const char*);
```

and then we can create a deduction guide in the form of

```
template<typename... Ts>
collection(Ts... ts) -> collection<decltype(type_map(ts))...>;
```

and now

```
auto n = collection{ 5, 0.5f, "123" };
```

will have `n` being a `collection<A, B, C>` as seen in this [live exmaple](https://godbolt.org/z/9v11fd376)

---

A "meta function" is the term I use for a function that doesn't actually do anything, it is just used to map one type into another.  The are only ever called in an unevaluated context like in `decltype` in the above example.